# How to change PHP files in DIV without reloading all page?

Tags: php

I know there are some articles about something like this but I can't figure it out. 
P.S. I'm new in programming so maybe my question is stupid.

All I wan't to do is to change 4 contents inside a  tag with clickable buttons (button1, button2, button3, button4)

When page loads user see only content_1.php.

```
<div id="content_box">
<? 
include 'content_1.php';
include 'content_2.php';
include 'content_3.php';
include 'content_4.php';

?>
</div>
```

Maybe somebody can show an example?

Thanks.

Comment: the question is vague and its hard to tell what you are trying to do. If there is "some articles" about it, then you might want to link to some of them so we get a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: first learn about ajax (it loads part of the page without refreshing whole page) and use one div for each .php and onClick of the particular button load the 'div'(i.e., php) using ajax

Answer (score 2):

use ajax requests, for reference use below link:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: That suffers from the [usual problem](http://bobby-tables.com/) of the dreadful W3Schools. Avoid that guide.

Comment: by assuming user don't know about ajax i gave w3schools links it's useful for beginners. once user understands about ajax he can refer other sites by him self

Comment: W3Schools teaches very bad practises. It isn't suitable for beginners because they don't know how to protect themselves.

Comment: but when i am beginner i also used that. I think now i learned ajax. And user wants the solution for his problem it's not about which site to refer as an example he can use that site

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that it is OK to give somebody something that will give them major security problems so long as it gives them what they want as well? If so, I have a car I want to sell you, I promise it won't blow up and injure you until it gets you too far away from me for you to complain.

Comment: i am not suggesting them to refer this site only, i am just telling start with this, later they can end up with other sites

Comment: Security needs to be dealt with as soon as it becomes a possible issue. Not as an afterthought discovered with additional research on another site.

Comment: Quentin: This link provides a brief, understandable answer to this question. When the programmer starts using a database, he will immediately run into the issue of SQL-injection. After that, he will be avare of that. But I can put this into another context: If this guide causes a problem, he will learn not to be a headless copy-paste programmer.

Answer (score 2):

You can either (A) send it all to the client and do do hide-and-show on the client side entirely, or you can (B) send the first block of content and load the rest on demand (via AJAX).

There are a few things to take into consideration when choosing between the two:

1. How often are users going to see other than the initial content (few times → B: Send only what's needed, a few will make another request)
2. How much data are we talking about (little → A: Send it all every time, fewer requests)
3. Does `include`-ing a PHP file have side-effects (it shouldn't!) (yes → B: Only include what's requested)

As for the first strategy, you could:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(box) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        document.getElementById('content_' + i).style = (i === box ? 'block' : 'none');
    }
}
</script>
<div id="content_box">
    <div id="content_1"><?php include 'content_1.php'; ?></div>
    <div id="content_2" style="display: none;"><?php include 'content_2.php'; ?></div>
    <div id="content_3" style="display: none;"><?php include 'content_3.php'; ?></div>
    <div id="content_4" style="display: none;"><?php include 'content_4.php'; ?></div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="show(1);">Show #1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="show(2);">Show #2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="show(3);">Show #3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="show(4);">Show #4</a>
```

**NOTICE**
This assumes that the interaction has to be on the same page. If a full page load is desired, just go with [`GET` parameters and a PHP `switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519325/how-to-change-php-files-in-div-without-reloading-all-page/6519429#6519429).

Answer (score 1):

there are more solutions, but the simplest would be, if you created four links like:

```
<a href="?content=1">show content 1</a>
```

then in the PHP side you create the logic by this user input:

```
<div id="content_box">
<?php 
switch($_GET['content']){
case 1: include 'content_1.php'; break;
case 2: include 'content_2.php'; break;
case 3: include 'content_3.php'; break;
case 4: include 'content_4.php'; break;
default: include 'content_1.php';
?>
</div>
```

By the way, `<? ?>` short tags are not recommended to use because are not anywhere supported because of configuration.

Comment: ...or as deepi said you can use AJAX. From your question it was not clear to me if you wanted an AJAX-like approach.

Comment: without loading page he want to load that div part so as my knowledge ajax is only option

Comment: I think $_GET['content'] variable should be checked if it's set at all before checking its content, not to get a notice on the PHP side (if php.ini is configured that way). For example, the value of the variable could be passed to another like this (before switch block): $content = isset($_GET['content'])? $_GET['content'] : null; //... and after that: switch($content){....}

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice to check whether variable exists before using it. 

I thought of it for a second, when made the post but figured: if $_GET['content'] is not initialised, it will be in this case with the default value of 0 ( <http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php> ) which would lead to the `default:` case.

Otherwise in production systems php.ini should not be configured in the way to show uninitalized variables, since that would reveal inside logic and lead to security issues. But also a good practise when used in development state.

Comment: yepp, of course, I know that it's getting evaluated so that it jumps to the "default" case. In development state, I think php.ini's error_reporting should be set to E_ALL|E_STRICT (or in PHP6 just E_ALL, which will also include E_STRICT), because this requires the strictest programming methods with which a part of sucks can be avoided, not disregarding different notices and errors.

Comment: Unfortunately many PHP-programmers (I'm not talking about you, but I can sadly see it in many forums) just suppress some PHP-errors to accelerate development while it can later cause some plus waste of time...while notices can be mostly avoided with just some more lines (or in many cases, just one plus line...).

Answer (score 1):

To make this you need to use some javascripts, but instead of invent your own maybe is better use something that exists. Try this http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ this should be what you need. After that you can use the ajax request to make the user loads only the part that he need

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of "pure" AJAX (which is also fine but its code is a little bit lengthy and not so easy to understand) you should use jQuery's AJAX API to reach the same functions in an easy way.

For example to load a file you should use jQuery's ***[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)*** function.
To be more specific, in your code it would look like this:

```
$('#content_box').load('content_1.php');
```

But I would like to show a complete example which also works in browsers without JavaScript or with JS disabled, because it also understands $_GET parameters. There are three solutions: 1. select and option tags, 2. buttons, 3. radio buttons.

So the code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Load contents with jQuery</title>
        <!-- jQuery CDN: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

        <!-- The code with jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#change_content_select').submit(function(){
                    var which_to_load = $('#sel_number').val(),
                    source_of_file = 'data/content_'+which_to_load+'.php';
                    $('#content_box').load( source_of_file );
                    return false;
                });

                $('#button_1, #button_2, #button_3, #button_4').click(function(){
                    var which_to_load = ( $(this).attr('id')+"" ).replace('button_', ''),
                    source_of_file = 'data/content_'+which_to_load+'.php';
                    $('#content_box').load( source_of_file );
                    return false;
                });

                $('#change_content_radio').submit(function(){
                    if( $('input[name=nrOfPage]:checked').val() === undefined ){
                        alert('Select which page to load first...');
                        return false;
                    }
                    var which_to_load = $('input[name=nrOfPage]:checked').val(),
                    source_of_file = 'data/content_'+which_to_load+'.php';
                    $('#content_box').load( source_of_file );
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Let's do it with select tags -->
        <div id="content_changing_select_tag">
            <b>Page to load with select:</b><br />
            Which page would you like to load?
            <form method="get" id="change_content_select" action="">
                <p>
                    <select id="sel_number" name="nrOfPage">
                        <option value="1">1st page</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd page</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd page</option>
                        <option value="4">4th page</option>
                    </select>
                    <!-- We put this submit button for compatibility with browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Change content" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <!-- Let's do it with buttons -->
        <div id="content_changing_buttons">
            <b>Page to load with buttons:</b><br />
            Which page would you like to load?
            <form method="get" id="change_content_buttons" action="">
                <p>
                    <input value="1" type="submit" id="button_1" name="nrOfPage" />
                    <input value="2" type="submit" id="button_2" name="nrOfPage" />
                    <input value="3" type="submit" id="button_3" name="nrOfPage" />
                    <input value="4" type="submit" id="button_4" name="nrOfPage" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <!-- Let's do it with radio buttons -->
        <div id="content_changing_radio">
            <b>Page to load with radio:</b><br />
            Which page would you like to load?
            <form method="get" id="change_content_radio" action="">
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="nrOfPage" value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" name="nrOfPage" value="2" />
                    <input type="radio" name="nrOfPage" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" name="nrOfPage" value="4" />
                    <!-- We put this submit button for compatibility with browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Change content" />            
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>OK, here comes the content...</div>

        <div id="content_box">
            <?php
            // default number of page to load
            $defaultPageNumber = '1';
            // check if content number is set
            $numberOfPageToInclude = isset($_GET['nrOfPage']) ? $_GET['nrOfPage'] : $defaultPageNumber;

            $options = array(
                'options' => array(
                    'min_range' => 1,
                    'max_range' => 4,
                    ));

            if (filter_var($numberOfPageToInclude, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) !== FALSE) {
                include 'data/content_' . $numberOfPageToInclude . '.php';
            } else {
                echo '<span style="color:red;">Wrong page number, including default page!</span><br />';
                include 'data/content_1.php';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And an example for the files to include:

**content_1.php** :

```
<h1>This is content <span style="color:red;font-size: 125%;">1</span>!</h1>
```

**content_2.php** :

```
<h1>This is content <span style="color:red;font-size: 125%;">2</span>!</h1>
```

**content_3.php** :

```
<h1>This is content <span style="color:red;font-size: 125%;">3</span>!</h1>
```

**content_4.php** :

```
<h1>This is content <span style="color:red;font-size: 125%;">4</span>!</h1>
```

Ask if something isn't clear.
Hope that helps someone!

(Btw. it's ***TESTED*** and ***WORKING***.)